# How to fix error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType in Keras

Tags: python, keras-layer

I'm trying to use shared Embedding layer for different input length, But I got errors as follows.

Code:

```
input1 = [Input(name = "input1", shape = (10,))]
input2 = [Input(name = "input2", shape = (10,))]
input3 = [Input(name = 'input3', shape = (1,))]
input4 = [Input(name = 'input4', shape = (1,))]
input5 = [Input(name = 'input5', shape = (1,))]
inputs= input1 + input2 + input3 + input4 + input5

embed = Embedding(name = 'embed', input_dim = 1000, output_dim = 20)
out1 = Flatten(name = 'output1')(embed(inputs[0]))
out2 = Flatten(name = 'output2')(embed(inputs[1]))
out3 = Flatten(name = 'output3')(embed(inputs[2]))
out4 = Flatten(name = 'output4')(embed(inputs[3]))
out5 = Flatten(name = 'output5')(embed(inputs[4]))

concat = Concatenate(name = 'concat')([out1, out2, out3, out4, out5])
result = Dense(name = 'result' + 'dense', units=1, activation='sigmoid')(concat)
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = result)

#model.summary()
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
input1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100,10))
input2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100,10))
input3 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100,1))
input4 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100,1))
input5 = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100,1))
dummy_y = (input4 > 0).reshape(-1, 1)
model_input = [input1, input2, input3, input4, input5]
model.fit(x = model_input, y = dummy_y)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\backprop.py in _num_elements(grad)
    615   if isinstance(grad, ops.IndexedSlices):
--> 616     return functools.reduce(operator.mul, grad.values._shape_tuple(), 1)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    617   raise ValueError("`grad` not a Tensor or IndexedSlices.")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\backprop.py in _aggregate_grads(gradients)
    597 
--> 598   if len(gradients) == 1:
    599     return gradients[0]

SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     27 dummy_y = (input4 > 0).reshape(-1, 1)
     28 model_input = [input1, input2, input3, input4, input5]
---> 29 model.fit(x = model_input, y = dummy_y)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    501       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    502       initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 503       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    504     finally:
    505       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 408             *args, **kwds))
    409 
    410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1846     if self.input_signature:
   1847       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1849     return graph_function
   1850 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2148         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2149         if graph_function is None:
-> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2039             arg_names=arg_names,
   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2042         self._function_attributes,
   2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    356         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    360 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in distributed_function(input_iterator)
     71     strategy = distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy()
     72     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
---> 73         per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))
     74     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
     75     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    758       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
    759                                 convert_by_default=False)
--> 760       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    761 
    762   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   1785       kwargs = {}
   1786     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 1787       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   1788 
   1789   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2130         self._container_strategy(),
   2131         replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
-> 2132       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2133 
   2134   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
--> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    293 
    294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py in train_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    262       y,
    263       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 264       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    265 
    266   if reset_metrics:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py in train_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, output_loss_metrics)
    309           sample_weights=sample_weights,
    310           training=True,
--> 311           output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
    312   if not isinstance(outs, list):
    313     outs = [outs]

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py in _process_single_batch(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    266           model._backwards(tape, scaled_total_loss)
    267         else:
--> 268           grads = tape.gradient(scaled_total_loss, trainable_weights)
    269           if isinstance(model.optimizer,
    270                         loss_scale_optimizer.LossScaleOptimizer):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
   1012         output_gradients=output_gradients,
   1013         sources_raw=flat_sources_raw,
-> 1014         unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
   1015 
   1016     if not self._persistent:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\imperative_grad.py in imperative_grad(tape, target, sources, output_gradients, sources_raw, unconnected_gradients)
     74       output_gradients,
     75       sources_raw,
---> 76       compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))

SystemError: PyEval_EvalFrameEx returned a result with an error set
```

The error occured when I tried to fit the model, however I try with first four inputs, I can run without the error, any suggestion that would be appreciated.
I jsut adding some traceback errors, Thank you in advance.

Comment: I ran into something similar and wasn't able to debug it. It seems like it has something to do with the concatenation of 5 or more embedding vectors. This gh issue may help: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36642